# Pacman not available on fresh MSYS2 install

Tags: windows, mingw, msys2

I just installed MSYS2 on windows 10 following instructions here : https://www.msys2.org/

After installation, a terminal opens, in which I type `pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc`

This results in an error "Command pacman, Shell Error: not found"
[image: error message]

Why is pacman not installed? Why is this a popup window and not a error in the terminal?

I note that my prompt is a simple $ instead of `<username>@<computername> UCRT64 ~`, I do not know if this is related.

I have `git-for-windows` installed on the same computer, and wanted to install MSYS2 alongside with it to install `minGW` and a compilation environment. I emptied my `~` folder but it changed nothing.

Comment: Were there any hints in using the installer, at https://www.msys2.org/docs/installer/, that might help?

Comment: I installed with the GUI installer: It showed "done" and no error in it's full output. I just checked the sha, it's ok. I don't see other infos in this page.